# how to find a value with local alias qualified package name in haskell template

Tags: haskell

If a package is imported as

```
import qualified Database.HDBC as H
```

How to get the [`Name`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#t:Name) value of variable `Database.HDBC.fromSql`?

```
lookupValueName "Database.HDBC.lookup" -- Q Nothing
lookupValueName "H.fromSql"            -- Q (Just "Database.HDBC.SqlValue.fromSql")
```

The second line works, but it assumes that the local alias is `H`. Is there any way to get the variable name under qualified local alias?